# Can't connect remotely to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb

I'm configuring my EC2 server. I managed to install php, laravel etc. (with a bit of suffering though). Now I

- created an user on MariaDB
- granted all permissions from remote
- enabled bind-address = 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf
- tested local login, works
- opened rules in the Security group for Mysql/Aurora, port 3306, TCP, all IPs, both incoming and outcoming

but still can't login from remote, I get

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'yyz.yyz.yyz.yyz' (110)
```

What can I do? I don't have any iptables of sort, everything is supposed to be plain simple... but it's not :-(

I'm trying to connect from outside the Amazon network, with this string

```
mysql -u myuser -pmypwd -h yyz.yyz.yyz.yyz -D myschema
```

Please notice that from the server itself I can connect using

```
mysql -u myuser -p -h localhost -P 3306 -D myschema
```

Thank you
Marco

P.S. For reference, here are my MariaDB users

```
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| host                                        | user      |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
| %                                           | myuser    |
| 127.0.0.1                                   | root      |
| ::1                                         | root      |
| ip-yyz-yy-zz-yyz.us-west-2.compute.internal | root      |
| localhost                                   | root      |
| localhost                                   | myuser    |
+---------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Please show us your connection string for connecting to MySQL.  Not that it necessarily matters with your current security rules, but are you trying to hit the DB from the outside, or from the EC2 node?

Comment: Added the connection string from both the server itself and outside network

Comment: Can you try also specifying port 3306 in the connection string you are using to connect from outside AWS (currently it does not list a port) ?

Comment: Did it. mysql -u myuser -pmypwd -h yyz.yyz.yyz.yyz -P 3306 -D myschema. Didn't work :-/ but nice try!

Comment: OK, next question.  Are you sure that the username and password are correct?  Are you also sure that the host you listed is the right one?

Comment: Are you sure that the username and password are correct? Yes :-) Are you also sure that the host you listed is the right one? What do you mean with "listed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good news and bad news.

- Good news: I solved the issue!
- Bad news: We all were right. It was enough to open the 3306 port in the Security Group. The issue was that - for reasons unknown to me - I kept seing the wrong security group. I logged off, logged in again and saw the right one. Enabled the port 3306 there and - magic - it worked!

Thank you to everybody who spent time in order to help mi fixing this!

Comment: Marco, when someone gives you the answer, you don't post your own answer and select it. O. Jones helped you solve your problem with his answer's last paragraph and the comments from his answer. He should get the check and the bounty.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I don’t care about the points. What’s important? The problem was solved, and explained clearly enough to help the next person.

Comment: I really thank O. Jones for his answer but - as I explained in the comment below his answer - I was trying to do something different and didn't need to add a *|root user or authorize internal/external IPs. Also the Tim Biegeleisen replies were useful but didn't take me anywhere I had not already been. Since I solved the issue by re-doing something I had already done but after a logoff/login I thought the right thing to do was to say "kudos to everybody, but mainly to myself!" and write down the answer. I still thank O. Jones and Tim for the time they spent on this issue though, I really do.

Answer (score 4):

EC2 instances have two IP addresses, internal and external.

It looks to me like your user table authorizes access from the internal IP address.

```
ip-yyz-yy-zz-yyz.us-west-2.compute.internal | root
```

Are you trying to connect to the internal address from outside AWS? That Doesn't Work™.

If you're trying to connect to the external address, you'll have to add it to your user list.

For troubleshooting but not production, you can add a `* | root` user.

You can also try https://xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz:3306 from a browser. It won't connect, but if it times out you know there's no route to that address from your machine. If it yields some kind of gibberish, immediately, you know the MySQL port is visible.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough reply. Actually I'm trying to connect with the myuser user, which should be enabled for any IP. Doesn't the % symbol in  "|%|myuser|" mean just that?

Comment: Also, I have a running webservice on my server. If I ping the host, say myhost.mydomain.com, I get the xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz IP. Should I add that IP anywhere specifically?

Answer (score 0):

In **AWS** there can be two possible issues with **MariaDB** one is security group you have to add port 3306. to add port go into AWS --> EC2 --> Network & Security --> Security Groups and created a new group that permitted 3306 from  static IP or 0.0.0.0/0 it will open access to globally. but if issue still there than you have to add the blow two line in file

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

and restart the mariadb service

```
netstat -nat |grep :3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

should look like this
and try to connect hopefully it will be resolved